# Google Admin SDK operations using Client Login failing with 403 code even with Auth Token

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I have downloaded [admin-cmd-line-sample](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/api-lib/java) for Java and its working fine with oAuth, I am able to create users and groups. I have Admin SDK enabled also API usage in Security settings.

But I have to use old ClientLogin mechanism to create users and groups.

When asking for Authorization Token, Client Login returns me a value, which I eventually set in http request header and call the remote service.

But I get

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I am using Client Login as follows.

```
ClientLogin authenticator = new ClientLogin();
authenticator.authTokenType = "apps";
authenticator.username = "foo@foo.com";
authenticator.password = "bar123#";
authenticator.transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

final Response response = authenticator.authenticate();

Directory client = new Directory.Builder(GoogleApacheHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {

        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
           httpRequest.getHeaders().setAuthorization(response.getAuthorizationHeaderValue());
        }

}).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

Above client instance than I am using to create a user or group.

```
Group group = new Group();
group.setEmail("foo@foo.com");
group.setName("bar group");
group.setDescription("bar group");
client.groups().insert(group).execute();
```

> If I make ***response.getAuthorizationHeaderValue()*** print on console, I
>   can see a long string value.

I am using version directory_v1-rev16-1.16.0-rc of google-api-services-admin

Would really appreciate if someone could point where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Admin SDK API does not support the deprecated [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps). You need to use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) authentication.